# How to track property changes in sub classes from the main class?

Tags: php

I am trying to create a changes tracking mechanism, inside of a class, that tracks properties that have been updated both in the main class properties and for properties in sub classes.

So far I have been able to accomplish, this for basic properties like, string, int, etc, but I'm struggling to make it work for properties like arrays and sub classed properties.

Here is what I have so far:

Main Class - Contact Class

```
class ContactObject {

    private bool $Journalling = false;

    private $Data = null;

    private ?string $ID = null;
    private ?string $State = null;
    private ?string $Label = null;
    private ?ContactNameObject $Name = null;
    private array $Phone = [];


    public function __construct($data = null) {
        $this->Data = (object) array();
        $this->Data->Original = (object) array();
        $this->Data->Changed = (object) array();
        $this->Name = new ContactNameObject();
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->$name = $value;
        if ($this->Journalling) {
            $this->Data->Changed->$name = $this->$name;
        } else {
            $this->Data->Original->$name = $this->$name;
        }
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        if (isset($this->$name)) {
            return $this->$name;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public function __isset($name) {
        return isset($this->$name);
    }

    public function activateJournal() {
        $this->Journalling = true;
    }

    public function addPhone(string $type, ?string $subtype, string $number) {
        $this->Phone[] = new ContactPhoneObject($type, $subtype, $number);
    }

}
```

Sub Class - Contact Name Class (Used in the Name property in main class)

```
class ContactNameObject {

    public ?string $Last;
    public ?string $First;
    public ?string $Other;
    public ?string $Prefix;
    public ?string $Suffix;
    public ?string $PhoneticLast;
    public ?string $PhoneticFirst;
    public ?string $PhoneticOther;
    public ?string $Aliases;
    
    public function __construct(
        ?string $last = null,
        ?string $first = null,
        ?string $other = null,
        ?string $prefix = null,
        ?string $suffix = null,
        ?string $phoneticlast = null,
        ?string $phoneticfirst = null,
        ?string $aliases = null
    ) {
        $this->Last = $last;
        $this->First = $first;
        $this->Other = $other;
        $this->Prefix = $prefix;
        $this->Suffix = $suffix;
        $this->PhoneticLast = $phoneticlast;
        $this->PhoneticFirst = $phoneticfirst;
        $this->Aliases = $aliases;
    }
}
```

Sub Class - Contact Phone Class (Used in the Phone Array in main class)

```
class ContactPhoneObject {

    public ?string $Type;
    public ?string $SubType;
    public ?string $Number;
    
    public function __construct(?string $type = null, ?string $subtype = null, ?string $number = null) {
        $this->Type = $type;
        $this->SubType = $subtype;
        $this->Number = $number;
    }
}
```

At the moment when I turn journaling on and update the basic main class properties, the changes do get tracked properly. But if I add and entry to the phone array property or remove one, that does not trigger the _get or _set in the main class. Same happens for any sub properties in the Name subclass

Thanks in advance Sebastian

I've search for an answer to this, but could not find a solution.

Comment: _"Sub Class - Contact Name Class (Used in the Name property in main class)"_ - so what you are calling a "sub class" doesn't actually really have anything to do with the "main" class (I expected to see `extends` being used, based on your phrasing), but is just a _completey arbitrary_ other class, and what makes it "sub" is simply the fact that you assigned it to a property of the "main" class ...? (That is a very weird way of phrasing it then, IMHO.)

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using the __get and __set magic methods, although they are a built in php feature.
[Here's](https://medium.com/@lukaspereyra8/php-magic-methods-a-powerful-yet-tricky-feature-fa1971b195bf) an article that gives a good overview why.

If you rely on your own imlementations you create more predictable behavior without magic.

One way to archieve this is by just implementing getters and setters, that track property changes in a private array property.

I would not create objects with properties dynamically because it's harder to read the code, if it gains complexity. Instead I would create a class that provides functionality to track the changes or just a simple array.

If your goal is to track changes within all your classes a variation of the [composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) might be helpful, where all your classes share an interface which defines a method to retrieve the changes of the respective class and all of its children.

As you call your class "subclass" I would recommend reading about [Composition vs Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) because these classes aren't really related by inheritance in the code you shared, except that one class is used by the other one.

Hope it helps!